# Using the appropriate date formatter in Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I have one issue related to jqgrid. I have date shown in jqgrid table like "2017-01-05 00:00:00.0 CST" .I want to change its format to "05/01/2017".how i can do it?

XML response:

```
<row class="Bill" id="3">
  .
  .
  .
  <billDate id="4">2017-01-05 00:00:00.0 CST</billDate>     
</row>
```

Jquerygrid XmlReader:

```
 xmlReader : {
           root : 'rows',
           row : 'row',
           page : 'reader>page',
           total : 'reader>total',
           records : 'reader>records',
           repeatitems : false
       }
```

Jquerygrid field model:

```
       name : 'billDate',
       index : 'billDate',
       xmlmap : 'billDate',
       sorttype : 'date',
       formatter : 'date',
       width : 130,
       resizable : true,
       aling : 'center'
```

i try with   `formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d/m/Y" }`   but that's not work. I understand that it is not a standard date. Is it possible to process it to show it as I require it?  how i can do it?

Comment: Please describe which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGrid or free-jqGrid or jqGrid version <=4.7. In the current version of Guriddo this is working as expected. Here [is example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/functionality/date_formatter/) . You may want to post more detailed XML response - I mean a part with two or more rows

Comment: The jqGrid   version is 3.8.2 Tony Tomov

Comment: Jquery components:
query-1.5.1.min.js  
query.filestyle.js   
query-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js  
query-ui-init.js                
jquery-1.4.4.min.js  
jquery.alerts.js     
jquery.timers-1.2.js  
jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js  
jsrsasign-4.7.0-all-min_sat-fix.js 
scriptbreaker-multiple-accordion-1.js

Comment: This is too old version.  It's hard to believe that this one is still being used. Instead, I will check it and let you know